# Recoil JS component re-rendering without state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, recoiljs

I've been trying to get pagination working with Recoil and I'm stuck. What seems to be happening is that my subscribed component is re-rendering without the updated state.

On my index page, I'm getting an initial payload from Firebase using NextJS SSR. That payload is passed as props to the page component and is then stored as an array in a Recoil atom.

The content is rendered with the **JobFeed** component which receives a Recoil selector that returns a filtered version of the state. This all works just fine.

```
const Index = ({initialJobs}) => {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useRecoilState(jobState);
  const jobList = useRecoilValue(filteredJobListState);

  const fallback = <div>Loading</div>

  useEffect(() => {
    if (jobs.length < 1) {
      setJobs(initialJobs)
    } else {
      setJobs(jobList)
    }
  }, [])
 
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <title>{SITE_TAGLINE}&nbsp;-&nbsp;{SITE_NAME}</title>
        </Head>
          <Masthead />
          <Filters />
          {
            (jobList.length < 1) ? <div>Loading</div> : 
            <JobFeed jobs={jobList}/>
          }
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}
```

The Recoil atom looks like this:

```
export const jobState = atom({
    key: "jobState",
    default: [],
});
```

And the filtered state selector looks like this:

```
export const filteredJobListState = selector({
    key: 'filteredJobListState',
    get: ({get}) => {
        // Get current filters
        const filters = get(filterState);

        // Get current job state
        const jobList = get(jobState);

        // Construct queries to return correct state object
        if (!filters || filters.category === "" || filters.state === "") {
            return jobList;
        } else {
            return jobFilter(jobList, filters);
        };

        // Check key value pairs and return filtered state
        function jobFilter(jobs, query) {
            return jobs.filter(job => {
                for (let key in query) {
                    if (job[key] === undefined || job[key] != query[key])
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        };
    }
});
```

Where I'm running into problems is with the pagination feature within the  component.

```
const JobFeed = ({ title, jobs }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useRecoilState(loadingState);
  const [postsEnd, setPostsEnd] = useRecoilState(postsEndState);   
  const [jobList, setJobList] = useRecoilState(jobState);

  const getMorePosts = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    // Get last post from current batch to run paginated query
    const last = jobList[jobList.length - 1];

    // Convert timestap for query if the format is incompatible
    const cursor = typeof last.createdAt === 'number' ? fromMillis(last.createdAt) : last.createdAt;
    
    const query = database
      .collection('jobs')
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      .startAfter(cursor)
      .limit(20);

    // Run query to get additional posts
    try {
      const newJobs = (await query.get()).docs.map(postToJSON);
      setJobList([...jobList, newJobs]);
      // The result of the console.log is the previous job state
      console.log(jobList)
      // Turn off loader
      setLoading(false);
      // Check to see if more posts available
      if (newJobs.length < 20) {
        setPostsEnd(true)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <section className="py-4">
        <Container>
            <SectionHeading>{title}</SectionHeading>
                {jobs.map((job) => {
                  return (
                    <JobCard 
                      key={job.id}
                      company={job.companyName}
                      position={job.position}
                      city={job.city}
                      state={job.state}
                      createdAt={job.createdAt}
                      category={job.category}
                      apply={job.application}
                      logo={job.companyLogo}
                    />
                  )
                })}
                <div className="border-t border-gray-100 my-8"></div>
                {!loading && !postsEnd && <button className="btn-green" onClick={getMorePosts}>Load more</button>}
                <Loader show={loading} />
                {postsEnd && "You've reached the end!"}
        </Container>
    </section>
  )
}
```

The jobState and filterState atoms are dependencies of the filteredJobState selector. Setting the filterState using useRecoilState triggers a re-render of the **JobFeed** component without any issues (but it's synchronous).

However, when the async getMorePosts function updates jobState, the component re-renders and throws the error, "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined."

When I console.log jobState *after* the setState call from getMorePosts, I receive the values from the previous state.

I've tried:

1. Wrapping the **JobFeed** component in a **Suspense** component with a check for SSR. Same issue.
2. Refactoring things to use getRecoilValueLoadable. Same issue.
3. Putting the getMorePosts logic in a selector. Same issue.
4. Putting the getMorePosts logic into useRecoilCallback. Threw a nested hook error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please make a reproducible example in a sandbox, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash Thanks for pushing me to do this. I found the issue when I rewrote a simple one-page version of the above on CodeSandbox. The issue boiled down to the lack of a spread operator in my state update.  

setJobList([...jobList, newJobs]) obviously should be setJobList([...jobList, ...newJobs])

